# Ant for Java not showing as installed but it is installed

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, opencv

today I was having problems and it was pertaining to getting opencv.3.3.0 working on my new computer. I never have had this issue but I switched the day before from using openjdk to oracle jdk and that seemed fine but I think it is what caused the problem not sure. Anyways, I am trying to get the `opencv330.jar` to build but it isn't because it says ant isn't installed but I have it on my computer. I installed it doing `sudo apt-get install ant` and that worked. I do `which ant` and get `/usr/bin/ant`. That is what I expect but when I am trying to build for opencv I run this command

```
~/opencv-3.3.0/build$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

It prints a lot of stuff. I assume it is looking for existing files and ones that aren't there and other things but then I see this

```
--   Java:
    --     ant:                         NO
    --     JNI:                         NO
    --     Java wrappers:               NO
    --     Java tests:                  NO
```

I do have ant installed, I don't care about the rest of them as they don't need to be satisfied I (not sure about wrappers and tests) but I want it to build the opencv330.jar but it can't without `ant` being a "missing". How can I fix this so that it knows that `ant` is installed on my computer and then it can build the jar?

Here is some info about my Java:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java
hagin@hagin-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ ^C
hagin@hagin-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51
hagin@hagin-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
hagin@hagin-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
hagin@hagin-ThinkPad-T440p:~$
```

Comment: Could it be a OpenJDK issue? Type `update-alternatives --query java` to see how many java you have installed in your computer and which java has higher priority.

Comment: its all a mess. I just want to restart again with everything. I have messed it up and things are all over the place @Redbob I updated the question with some more info about my Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Oracle JAVA, you can follow this guide I always do when I want to install it:

[How To Manually Install Oracle Java on a Debian or Ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps)

If you prefer continue to using OpenJDK, just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-8-jdk
```

After that, verify if `$JAVA_HOME` is functional.
Type `printenv` to see if it's present.

Or type `ls $JAVA_HOME`, it will list java installed folder.

To enable it:

- Type `command -v java` to take note of java path;
- edit `~/.bashrc` file and append this line at the end:

  `export JAVA_HOME=<java path>`

In addition, it's necessary defining ANT_HOME to make it work.

You need append `export ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant` (exampled from this question)
to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I did this then tried to check JAVA_HOME and I got this `ls $JAVA_HOME
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51': No such file or directory`

Comment: alright I fixed the path problems

Comment: but ant won't get installed.

Comment: To make ant "work", you must set $ANT_HOME variable. Add `export ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant` to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: that worked out :) but when I do `ls $JAVA_HOME` I get `ls: cannot access '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51': No such file or directory
` but when I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51
`. How do I change this to be valid?

Comment: What is the output of `command -v java`? And `java -version`?

Comment: I get  `/usr/bin/java`  and for version I get `openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
`

Comment: So to must declare `export JAVA_HOME=/use/bin/java`

Comment: thanks so much I was able to fix everything and get it installed correctly!